# How to use Font Awesome 6 Pro icons in TinyMCE 6?

Tags: webpack, font-awesome, font-awesome-6

I want to use Font Awesome 6 Pro icons in TinyMCE 6, but I facing issues with this:

If I try to use free version of iconset it works with this code:

```js
options = {
  content_css: [
    'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/css/all.css'
  ]
}
```

...but I don't have CDN link for Pro version.

I use Webpack to bundle things, so I tried to create a `fontawesome-pro.css` file, but I didn't found any importable SCSS files in Font Awesome 6 Pro packages.

I use these packages in the project (if it's neccessary, I can add more packages):

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
```

I want to create a single CSS file, what contains all Font Awesome 6 Pro icon styles.

How can I bundle a CSS file for my Font Awesome 6 Pro icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I downloaded the Pro zip file and added to my project as asset and there is a CSS file, and I was abel to load it.